# Error with swift command in terminal in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, swift, ubuntu-15.04

I installed the open sourced version of Swift from **[swift.org](https://swift.org)** for Ubuntu 15.10, but I am running Ubuntu 15.04 in my machine. Now when I executed the `swift` command in the terminal it raising the following error.

> swift/usr/bin/repl_swift:error while loading shared libraries:
>   libicuuc.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory
>
> error: failed to stop process at REPL breakpoint

I ran the following command to ensure libicu52 is installed.

```
 sudo apt-get install libicu52
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is better asked on the swift-users mailing list.

Comment: maybe a typo, but swift asks for version 55, while you provide version 52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this as well

```
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb

It worked for me

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions where it complains about `libicuuc.so.57: cannot open shared object file` (version **57**), use the following:

```
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu57_57.1-6ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu57_57.1-6ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb
```

In general, you can search [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libicu57) for the version you need.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need libicu-dev unless you are building Swift from source.  The problem is that, as pointed out by gengisdave, libicu52 is installed on the machine, but libicu55 is required.  A few things you might try:

See if `apt-get install libicu55` is going to install the needed version.

Install the binary distribution intended for Ubuntu 14.04.  That one requires libicu52, which you do have on the system.  *This may or may not work, and if it does at first, it may break unexpectedly later depending on what you are doing.*

This is even worse, but you might try it if you are just experimenting. Use `dpkg -L libicu52` to find out where libicuuc.so.52 is located and create a symlink to it, named libicuuc.so.55, in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Before the 8th of December this used to work

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" | sudo tee --
append /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```